# yii2, RBAC, для чего нужны permission при создании роли

Tags: yii2, rbac

Столкнулся с не пониманием при разработке админки с помощью rbac на yii2.
для чего нужно задать permission

```
$createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
```

если в контроллере можно подключить `access controller`, и проверять по роли

```
'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'view'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['moderator'],

                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['createPost', 'index', 'delete', 'update'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

Ведь в будущем я могу создавать новые функции, которые я просто задам в access и доступ будет

Или суть такова,чтобы роль администратора унаследовала роль модератора и + сверху имела доступ к своим функциям? И тогда в будущем мне нужно добавить новую permission для роли , при создании новой функции?

Никак не могу понять сути permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Это полезно для группировки доступов. Например есть пермишн post, который открывает доступ ко всем экшенам контроллера. Так мы группируем экшены. Далее создаем роль и в нее группируем пермишены. Для роли модератор у нас обычно post, news, article и так далее. А роли уже раздает юзерам.

Если у нас появляется новый экшн, мы просто добавляем его в пермишн и у всех модераторов он открыт. Также и с новым разделом. Создаем пермишн и добавляем его к нужной роли. Все модераторы получают доступ к новому разделу.

В других случаях придется бегать по всем юзерам и вспоминать у кого должен быть доступ, а у кого нет. С помощью пермишенов можно гибко настраивать доступ к разным экшенам. Например только чтение и редактирования.  Удалять нельзя. Или только чтение.

Когда пермишенов становится слишком много, то очень легко запутаться.  Поэтому рекомендую называть их как контроллеры. Если доступ в модуле, то добавляем префикс. Например content _ post для всех экранов. , а content_post_read только для чтения.

Более специфичные доступы и роли хорошо бы подкрепить описанием.